# porque no puedo tener 2 returns como en un if con un operador ternario? y porque es undefined?

Tags: javascript, funciones

porque en mi funcion es undefined si no puedo tener dos returns en mi operador ternario como en un if... segunda pregunta podria usar un if en ese arrow function?... tercera podria usar una funcion normal en vez de arrow function?y como seria de ser posible? muchas gracias.

```js
function mutation(arr) {

    const word1= arr[0].split("")
    const word2= arr[1].split("")
    console.log(word2.forEach(elem => word1.includes(elem)? true :  false)) 
}

mutation(["hello", "hey"]);
```

Answer (score 3):

Te muestra undefined en consola por qué forEach siempre retorna undefined, esta función es solo para recorrer un array.

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Podrías dar mas detalle de lo que quiere que haga la función mutation para ayudarte a construirla

Answer (score 2):

Efectivamente `forEach` es una mala opción para lo que desees hacer con un `return` interno, según esta otra respuesta [What does `return` keyword mean inside `forEach` function? [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34653650/13636459) `return` no tiene la capacidad de parar un 'for-loop' y causa errores si tratas de hacerlo, al final no devuelve nada.

Aunque viendo un poco lo que tratas de hacer, es probable que quieras usar `array.map()` ya que este sí devuelve un mapeo evaluando cada elemento en la lista. Ese elemento puedes 'sacarlo' de la función con `return`, luego mostrarlo en consola desde afuera.

```js
function mutation(arr) {

    const word1= arr[0].split("")
    const word2= arr[1].split("")
    return word2.map(elem => word1.includes(elem)? true :  false)
}

console.log(mutation(["hello", "hey"]));
```